# Get value from select outside of ionChange Method

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

I have two select menus with the point when setting the second select, i need the value from the first select. So its outside of the scope i guess, i was thinking to the get the value from the ngModul like `arrayOne.getValue()` or so , but does not work.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>One</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="arrayOne" (ionChange)="getTwo($event)">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let one of ones">{{one}}</ion-option>            

  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Two</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="arrayTwo" (ionChange)="getXXXX($event)">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let two of twos">{{two}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

**Typescript**

```
getTwo(one) 
{
  //  one is available here
}

getXXXX(two)
{
 // two is available here
 // but i need the value from first select (one) here as well 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using two way data binding in your select, you can directly access using the variable name as follows:

```
@component{

}
class YourClassName{
     let arrayOne;
     let arrayTwo;
     constructor(){

     }

     getTwo(one) 
     {
      //  one is available here
     }

     getXXXX(two)
     {
      // two is available here
      alert(this.arrayOne);
     }
}
```